# Equal column widths on R formattable

Tags: r, report, htmlwidgets, formattable

I am using the formattable package to make some reports directly from R and I need the columns using the normalize_bar "style" have the same width, so that can compare value between columns.

The following example shows two columns that have very similar values (minimum and maximum values are equal) but have a different width, losing the graphic detail of the bar ("Test.number.1.score" and "test2_score").

```
library(formattable)

df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:10,
  name = c("Bob", "Ashley", "James", "David", "Jenny", 
           "Hans", "Leo", "John", "Emily", "Lee"), 
  age = c(28, 27, 30, 28, 29, 29, 27, 27, 31, 30),
  grade = c("C", "A", "A", "C", "B", "B", "B", "A", "C", "C"),
  Test.number.1.score = c(8.9, 9.5, 9.6, 8.9, 9.1, 9.3, 9.3, 9.9, 8.5, 8.6),
  test2_score = c(9.1, 9.1, 9.2, 9.1, 8.9, 8.5, 9.9, 9.3, 9.1, 8.6),
  final_score = c(9, 9.3, 9.4, 9, 9, 8.9, 9.25, 9.6, 8.8, 8.7),
  registered = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

formattable(df, list(
  age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
  grade = formatter("span", style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", 
                                               style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
  area(col = c(Test.number.1.score, test2_score)) ~ normalize_bar("pink", 0.2),
  final_score = formatter("span",
                          style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
                          x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
  registered = formatter("span",
                         style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
                         x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
))
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Directly using the formatter solves this problem. You want the same width for both the columns.

When I looked at the code of color_bar function I found that their is a width attribute for the width of colored portion. Basically I am modifying that property to get the desired result.

first set a width say 150 px

```
fixedWidth = 150
```

and change your `formattable` function call to

```
formattable(df, list(
    age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
    grade = formatter("span", style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", 
                                                 style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
    test2_score = formatter(.tag = "span", style = function(x) style(display = "inline-block", 
                                                                     direction = "rtl", `border-radius` = "4px", `padding-right` = "2px", 
                                                                     `background-color` = csscolor("pink"), width = paste(fixedWidth*proportion(x),"px",sep="") )),
    Test.number.1.score = formatter(.tag = "span", style = function(x) style(display = "inline-block", 
                                                                             direction = "rtl", `border-radius` = "4px", `padding-right` = "2px", 
                                                                             `background-color` = csscolor("pink"), width = paste(fixedWidth*proportion(x),"px",sep="") )),


    final_score = formatter("span",
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
                            x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
    registered = formatter("span",
                           style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
                           x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
))
```

Note the  `width = paste(fixedWidth*proportion(x),"px",sep="")` for changing to fixed width and  `csscolor("pink")` to change the color to pink inside formatter.

The desired output looks like below
[image: The Final Report]

**UPDATE**

Or more cleanly you can create your own `color_bar` function namely `my_color_bar` by changing its `width` argument as below

```
my_color_bar <- function (color = "lightgray", fixedWidth=150,...) 
{
        formatter("span", style = function(x) style(display = "inline-block", 
                                                direction = "rtl", `border-radius` = "4px", `padding-right` = "2px", 
                                                `background-color` = csscolor(color), width = paste(fixedWidth*proportion(x),"px",sep=""), 
                                                ...))
}
```

And use it in your `formattable` function call as

```
formattable(df, list(
    age = color_tile("white", "orange"),
    grade = formatter("span", style = x ~ ifelse(x == "A", 
                                                 style(color = "green", font.weight = "bold"), NA)),
    test2_score = my_color_bar(color="pink",width = 100),
    Test.number.1.score = my_color_bar(color="pink",width=100),


    final_score = formatter("span",
                            style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(rank(-x) <= 3, "green", "gray")),
                            x ~ sprintf("%.2f (rank: %02d)", x, rank(-x))),
    registered = formatter("span",
                           style = x ~ style(color = ifelse(x, "green", "red")),
                           x ~ icontext(ifelse(x, "ok", "remove"), ifelse(x, "Yes", "No")))
))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This solves it completely. Best regards!